# Есть затруднения при парсинге страницы. Помогите разобраться

Tags: angularjs

Станицы для парсинга:
1) http://wotreplays.ru/site/12068516?secret=96148d68d7220e8637d87133d47b2114#stats
2) http://wotreplays.ru/site/12068516?secret=96148d68d7220e8637d87133d47b2114#teams
статистика боя (реплей) Wold of Tanks.
При загрузке в браузере через командную строку второй ссылки #teams открывается нужная вкладка (Командный результат) - здесь все нормально.
При парсинге c помощью curl библиотеки с параметром url:  http://wotreplays.ru/site/12068516?secret=96148d68d7220e8637d87133d47b2114#teams
возвращается html код страницы http://wotreplays.ru/site/12068516?secret=96148d68d7220e8637d87133d47b2114#stats.
Url одинаковы, разница в окончании #stats, #teams. по умолчанию #stats.
Я вижу, что здесь используются директивы ng-hide, ng-show для задания видимости блока (по нажатию на вкладку "Командный результат"). Возможно это все обрабатывает Angular (JS-скрипт не могу найти).

```
function curl_get($url, $referer = 'http;//www.google.com'){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);                        // Не считывать заголовки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; ry:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Fifefox/38.0");  // указаваем браузер откуда пришел запрос
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);                // Переходить по редиректам (чаще всего ставится)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);                // Содержимое заголовка от куда был сделан запрос ('http;//www.google.com).
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                // Ответ сервера сохранять в переменную, а не на экран
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFullP);    // Запись кук в файл
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, ScookieFullP);     // Получение кук из файла, не работает без записи кук в файл 
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');   //Отправка куки (Содержимое заголовка «User-Agent:» для использования в HTTP-запросе.)
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);             // отправляем куки
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);           // POST запрос (для заполнения форм) 'name=Дима&surname=Трепачев' или ['name'=>' Дима', 'surname'=>'Трепачев']
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);               // ПРОКСИ (изменение IP адресов, для обхода возможной защиты сайта)
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT__INTERFACE, $ip);             // ПРОКСИ - если на сервере не настоящие прокси, представляемся 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

return $data;
}

```
$url = curl_get('http://wotreplays.ru/site/12068516?secret=96148d68d7220e8637d87133d47b2114#teams');    
$TextPage = curl_get($url);
print_r($TextPage);
```

Вопрос: что и как сделать, чтобы спарсить вторую страницу с параметром #teams (Командный результат).

Comment: Причём здесь AngularJS?

Comment: Я на 100% не утверждаю.

Comment: В get запросе почему-то отсекается #teams